# MySQL : Slow show databases;

Tags: mysql, show, database-schema

We are currently using a MySQL Server version 5.5.35 x86 - Win64

When we run the command :

> SHOW DATABASES;

As root user :

```
     2640 lines in 0,125 sec. (+ 0,015 sec. network)
```

As user with only read only access :

```
     2634 lines in 2,355 sec. (+ 0,016 sec. network)
```

Same reaction with :

> SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA;

Any ideas, why so slow ? It's the same query, only other user rights.

---

```
Edit:
Result of the profiling as suggested by @APaul.
```

- Status;            Duration
- starting;          0.000041
- Opening tables;    0.000158
- System lock;       0.000010
- init;              0.000010
- optimizing;        0.000007
- statistics;        0.000015
- preparing;         0.000009
- executing;         2.613761 ; root : 0.130849
- Sending data;      0.005739
- end;               0.000006
- query end;         0.000002
- closing tables;    0.000001
- removing tmp table;0.001469
- closing tables;    0.000004
- freeing items;     0.000165
- logging slow query;0.000005
- cleaning up;       0.000007

Comment: Did you try to do an explain plan on select schema_name from information_schema.schemata to see if there is any difference between root and r/o user plans?

Comment: Also, do you run the SQL from the native SQL client (mysql command), or using some foreign tools? Tools often perform additional queries that could depend on privileges.

Comment: I don't understand you first suggestion.

I tried the queries in both environment. It the same via the command line of via HeidiSQL.

Comment: Was just to discard possible interaction from SQL tool. If result is the same in both cases, it's not related to the tool. I can't help you further since I use MariaDB under Linux, where I couldn't reproduce the issue (fast with root and read only user).

Answer (score 0):

No this does not seem to be related to privileges. There might be some internal caching that is making it faster for user "root". But privileges has nothing to do with the query being slow.

Also check

[Do mysql user privileges influence performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704321/do-mysql-user-privileges-influence-performance)

Comment: If we run multiple time the queries, the performance are the same, no speed up.

Comment: Caching is just an idea. You can also check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911276/how-much-does-grant-permission-checking-affect-mysql-performance

Comment: Profiling :
Status              Duration
starting;           0.000041
Opening tables;     0.000158
System lock;        0.000010
init;               0.000010
optimizing;         0.000007
statistics;         0.000015
preparing;          0.000009
executing;          2.613761; root : 0.127287
Sending data;       0.005739
end;                0.000006
query end;          0.000002
closing tables;     0.000001
removing tmp table; 0.001469
closing tables;     0.000004
freeing items;      0.000165
logging slow query; 0.000005
cleaning up;        0.000007